# I am Aussie who lives and work in the UK I am travelling to Brazil but I have no visa, what are my best options?

Tags: visas, australian-citizens, brazil, uk-residents

I am Aussie who lives and work in the UK I am travelling to Brazil but I have no visa, what are my best options?

Comment: What do you mean by "best options"?  Getting the required visa?  Sneaking across the border? Attempting to fly to Brazil with no visa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply online for an e-Visa http://cglondres.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/e-visa.xml
Visitor Visas issued electronically are valid for a maximum of 2 (two) years, for stays of up to 90 (ninety) days per year.

Comment: Warning: The actual site it links to to apply for an e-visa has an invalid TLS certificate chain, and a [variety of other TLS configuration problems](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=formulario-mre.serpro.gov.br). It is not safe to proceed until they fix it. In other words, don't ignore the browser warning.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was about to look at that myself and saw those warnings and said "hell no".

Comment: @Michael Hampton I didn’t get a browser warning when I clicked on the VFSglobal link

Comment: @Traveller Which link? The actual link to the Brazilian government e-visa site is the one I'm referring to.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The link Traveller included in his Answer takes one to the Embassy of Brazil in London, UK. That Embassy page generates no notices of certificate issues, notes that VFS Global is the "outsourced company responsible for processing, and provides VFS' link as well. The VFS link https://brazil.vfsevisa.com/brazil/online/home/index also loads without a peep.

Comment: @David No, it's the next link, the one you would click if you actually were to apply to a visa, which has the problem. It says: "Click here to access the e-Visa application form (select the option ‘e-Visa’)." But don't.

Answer (score 3):

Your only option is to get the visa you need which, apparently, is an e-visa. You won't be allowed onto the plane without it.